# Why is this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deletion

[This post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43377) answers the question and gives information that is not just a link (what happens to Arjuna):

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the link to the answer? Or take a screenshot and embed it in your question post itself.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto This is the question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8824/what-happened-to-pandavas-in-future-lives/43377#43377. I reposted the answer exactly.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I added a screenshot as well

Comment: Read the question: **"What happened to Pandavas in future lives?"** I don't see your post answering the question at all. Also Pandya already pointed out in his comment **"link only"** answers are not considered. He also hyperlinked Meta post where it is explained why link-only answers are not considered.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the reason is already covered in the comment by the moderator before deleting the post.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It states what happens to Arjuna, a Pandava, in his future life.

Comment: I also don't understand other parts of your answer, especially second para and 3rd para after the link. To me it looks unnecessary contents.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Arjuna went riding on Harinagara, who is an avatar of Vishnu

Comment: Let's continue discussion in chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Harinagara is clearly part of the horses of the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse from Christianity (the second time Christianity is referenced in the Khand) (by the verses prior). That adds in some important context for the symbolism at play.

Comment: Okay I added the context from the first chapter, so is it okay now?

Comment: Update: Answer is undeleted now after revision.

Comment: @Pandya Better to convert your comment to an answer to bring proper closure to this meta post.

Comment: 'I’m voting to close this question because the reason is already covered in the comment by the moderator before deleting the post' - doesn't seem like a valid closure reason for a meta post. Someone needs to post an answer explaining what was wrong with the original answer and what needs to be corrected. @TheLittleNaruto